# Copying only specific symbolic links with rsync?

Tags: rsync

I have a folder structure that I want to copy using rsync, in which the structure is a series of backups from which I only want to copy the latest (which can be identified using a symbolic link), like so:

```
/backups
    /foo
        /2019-05-01
        /2019-06-01
        /latest -> 2019-06-01
    /bar
        /2019-05-20
        /2019-06-20
        /latest -> 2019-06-20
```

And so-on; what I would like to do is, using a single rsync command, copy **only** the `latest` backup from each folder, while otherwise mimicking the structure. To this end I came up with the following command:

```
rsync -rptgoDLm --include '*/' --include '/*/latest/**' --exclude '*' user@remote:/backups /some/local/path
```

Basically an archive with `--copy-links` and some include/exclude trickery to select only the `/*/*/latest` branches (plus `-m` to avoid a bunch of empty directory structures). This works fine except for one problem; if any of these branches contains symbolic links, then these are also copied as their targets, rather than just as plain symbolic links.

What I really need to be able to do is **only** use `--copy-links` behaviour with the `latest` symbolic links, while using another behaviour (e.g- that of `--links`) for any others that are encountered.

Is such a thing a possible with a single rsync command? My aim is to be able to run this without having to know what the immediate contents of `/backups` is, so that if I add anything new (e.g- `/backups/baz`) then it will copy automatically.

**Update**:
To clarify, the resulting directory structure I'd like to see on the destination would be:

```
/backups
    /foo
        /latest
    /bar
        /latest
```

i.e- I only need the latest version of each backup on the target (the target itself will handle the backup history in another way).

Comment: Will your destination always have copies of the previous directories, i.e. `foo/2019-05-01` and `bar/2019-05-20` in your example?

Comment: Can you diagram the resulting directory structure you want in `/some/local/path`?

Comment: @JimL. I've updated the question to reflect the intended destination structure; basically I want to treat the `latest` symbolic links as directories and copy only them to the destination, without resolving any other links contained within.

Comment: @roaima I've updated the question to give a sample of the intended structure I want on the destination; basically I want to treat the `latest` symbolic links as directories and copy only them to the destination, but without resolving any symbolic links contained within.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to fit your requirements

```
rsync -avR user@remote:'/backups/*/latest/' /some/local/path/
```

The `-R` flag effectively "copies" the entire source path into the destination and the resulting backups will land as `/some/local/path/backups/{whatever}/latest`.

If you find you don't want the entire source path you can include `/./` to indicate the point from which the path should be copied across to the destination. For example, `/backups/./foo/latest/` would result in `/some/local/path/foo/latest/` (i.e. the `/backups` component has been skipped). There's lots more detail in the documentation (`man rsync`).

Comment: I need an additional `/` after `latest`, but it works like a charm!

Comment: Aha! This does the trick; like Freddy I had to add a trailing slash (so `/backups/*/latest/`), I also found in the documentation for `-R` that I can control the path information with `./`, so for example can do `/backups/./*/latest/` to only get the structure starting from the wildcard.

Comment: @Freddy ah yes, I'd missed off the `-k` flag, but appending a trailing slash would work even better. I've fixed my answer, thank you.

Comment: @Haravikk yes that's right, but I didn't mention the `/./` feature because your target path in your question seemed to match the source and I didn't want to add unnecessary complexity. I've updated my answer for future reference.